# EOFError: Ran out of input (xlwings)

Tags: python, package, eof, xlwings, eoferror

I'm getting this error out of nowhere when I try to import xlwings. I don't know what's happening, and I would really appreciate some help! I don't know what I did, xlwings was working just fine for me yesterday.

```
import xlwings as xw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-c1395691fe55>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwings as xw
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _xlwindows as xlplatform
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 26, in <module>
    from win32com.client import Dispatch, CoClassBaseClass, CDispatch, DispatchEx, DispatchBaseClass
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import gencache
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 660, in <module>
    __init__()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 60, in __init__
    _LoadDicts()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\envML39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 113, in _LoadDicts
    version = p.load()
EOFError: Ran out of input
```